# need help for Calculator (doesn't take enter key )

Tags: c#

I want to use the Enter key as = in the calculator and I inserted code that checks whether the user pressed the Enter key in the form key press, but the code in this if statement never evaluates
Here is my code   :

```
    // perform input form keys or buttons
    private void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (result.Text == "0" || operation_pressed)
            result.Clear();                    // used to clear textbox 

        operation_pressed = false;
        Button btn = (Button)sender;           // store argument value enterd by user 
        if (btn.Text == ".")
        {
            if (!result.Text.Contains("."))
                result.Text = result.Text + btn.Text;

        }
        else
        result.Text = result.Text + btn.Text;
    }

    // perform CE operation
    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        result.Text = "0";
        label1.Text = "  ";
        value = 0;
    }

    // perform operator click event when user press any operational key 
    private void operation_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Button bt = (Button)sender;
        if(value != 0)
        {
            if (bt.Text == "√")
            {
                result.Text = Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                value = Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(result.Text));
            }
            equal.PerformClick();
            operation_pressed = true;
            operation = bt.Text;
            label1.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }
        else if (bt.Text == "√")
        {
            result.Text = Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
            value = Math.Sqrt(Double.Parse(result.Text));
        }
        else
        {

            operation = bt.Text;
            value = double.Parse(result.Text);
            operation_pressed = true;
            label1.Text = value + " " + operation;
        }

    }

    // perform actual operations on values, and show result on textbox
    private void equal_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = " ";

        switch (operation)
        {
            case "+":
                result.Text = (value + double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "-":
                result.Text = (value - double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "x":
            case "*":
                result.Text = (value * double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                break;

            case "/":
                result.Text = (value / double.Parse(result.Text)).ToString();
                break;


            default:
                break;

        }
        value = int.Parse(result.Text);
        operation = " ";
    }

    // this method is used to take input from keyboard 
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.KeyChar.ToString())
        { 
            case "0":
                zero.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "1":
                one.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "2":
                two.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "3":
                three.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "4":
                four.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "5":
                five.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "6":
                six.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "7":
                seven.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "8":
                eight.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "9":
                nine.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "+":
                add.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "-":
                sub.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "*":
                mul.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "/":
                div.PerformClick();
                break;
            case "=":
                equal.PerformClick();
                break;

            default:
                break;

        } //end switch 

        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
            equal.PerformClick();
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
            button17.PerformClick();

    }

    // used to delete last insert character from textbox
    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sample = result.Text;
        int a = sample.Length - 1;
        result.Text = sample.Remove(a); 
    }


}
```

code works fine but "Enter Key Condition" isn't working... 
Now what is the problem, How to Solve It ?

Comment: What does "isn't working" entail? error? no output?

Answer (score 1):

You could change this bit:

```
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    equal.PerformClick();
if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    button17.PerformClick();
```

To:

```
private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // ... your other code

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        equal.PerformClick();
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
        button17.PerformClick();
}
```

**Notice that I use the `KeyUp` event of the form instead of `KeyPress`**. This will enable you to use the `KeyCode` property of `e` and you don't have to cast anything to `char`.

Ideally, you should then also modify your switch statement to:

```
switch(e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Back:
        button17.PerformClick();
        break;
    // etcetera
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of `System.Windows.Forms.Form` class as below:

```
//when Enter key is pressed anywhere on form, yourEqualButton's Click event is fired.
yourForm.AcceptButton = yourEqualButton;
```

Also, there is a [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property that might be of use for `Esc` key press.